# How do I read the last line in the console output?

Tags: java, console, output, console-application

So im trying to make a Java program that uses adb and fastboot to root my Nexus 6P. I have a class that can run the commands, but I need to capture the device ID from the output. when I run `adb` or `fastboot` the output either looks like one of the three options below

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
5VT7N16324000434          device
```

or

```
List of devices attached
5VT7N16324000434          device
```

or

```
5VT7N16324000434          device
```

Now I need to capture the `5VT7N16324000434` and save it to a string. Though it will not always be the same. I have searched for hours with nothing helpful, and have no idea where to even start.

I run adb with this class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellCommand {

public static void main(String inputCommand) {

    ExecuteShellCommand obj = new ExecuteShellCommand();

    String command = inputCommand;

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

    System.out.println(output);

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}

}
```

I then need to read the out put for `5VT7N16324000434` or any string that could be in that place.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I have no idea where to start

Comment: How do you run `adb`?

Comment: I updated the question as I could not paste my code here and links were not working

@ScaryWombat

Comment: *I updated the question*  - as you should.  Now what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Any of the 3 outputs in the question. There's 3 because it depends on if adb is running or not and if the Nexus 6P is in the bootloader

Comment: so as it is the last line, you do not need to append each line, you need the keep the last line read.  When you return this line you can split it on white space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the only solution that come's up to my mind, is to route the `PrintStream` (`System.out`) and assign every line that gets printed to a String called `lastLine` or something. You can then get the device ID using a regex expression that removes the spaces/tabs after the actual device ID
like this -> (`DEVICEID          device`) to (`DEVICEID`) or just replace every space using `String.replaceAll(" ", "");` and the "device" word using `String.replace("device", "");`. I hope I could help you, as I'm fairly new to this community.

Edit:
Here's the code that assigns the last line to a String:

```java
private String lastLine;

public void construct() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
        public void println(String s) {
            lastLine = s;
            super.println(s);
        }
    });
}
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English